# SVG absolute line marker size

Tags: svg, markers

I've got a bunch of SVGs representing a trip using a polyline.

I'm using non-scaling-stroke vector effect to make sure that each of the polylines is rendered with an absolute width. So when the viewBox's dimension changes, the width of the polyline does not.

At the ends of the mentioned polylines, I wanted to put markers. I would like to have the markers absolutely sized as well. I thought this should be easy by setting the marker units to strokeWidth.

In contrast to what happens with the stroke of the polyline, the size of the markers at the end of a polyline, does change along with the size of the viewBox.

Below I've included an example in where I used simple circles for markers.

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="131890.80533333332 85178.93015415945 198.25991111111944 205.10300513348193">
  <defs>
    <marker id="end" markerHeight="4" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" orient="0deg" refX="8" refY="16" viewBox="0 0 16 20">
      <circle cx="8" cy="16" fill="#000" r="4"></circle>
    </marker>
    <marker id="start" markerHeight="4" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" orient="0deg" refX="8" refY="16" viewBox="0 0 16 20">
      <circle cx="8" cy="16" fill="#000" r="4"></circle>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <polyline fill="none" marker-end="url(#end)" marker-start="url(#start)" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" points="132089.06524444444, 85384.03315929293 131890.80533333332, 85178.93015415945">
    </polyline>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="132038.56071111112 85364.68902323228 50.557866666669725 19.330493533576373">
  <defs>
    <marker id="end" markerHeight="4" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" orient="0deg" refX="8" refY="16" viewBox="0 0 16 20">
      <circle cx="8" cy="16" fill="#000" r="4"></circle>
    </marker>
    <marker id="start" markerHeight="4" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" orient="0deg" refX="8" refY="16" viewBox="0 0 16 20">
      <circle cx="8" cy="16" fill="#000" r="4"></circle>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <polyline fill="none" marker-end="url(#end)" marker-start="url(#start)" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" points="132038.56071111112, 85364.68902323228 132089.1185777778, 85384.01951676585">
    </polyline>
  </g>
</svg>
```

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/u4bmupza/3/

Am I missing some SVG attributes or should I calculate the size of the markers manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke` was first introduced in [SVG 1.2 Tiny](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/). That was a subset of SVG intended for for  mobile devices with limited power.  SVG 1.2 didn't have markers, so this issue wasn't a problem.

`vector-effect` was about the only thing from SVG 1.2 Tiny that browsers ended up implementing.  Unfortunately, this problem was obviously missed at that time, and I guess no one has bothered to report it as a bug.  Though I've seen it asked about on S.O. previously.

The good news is that the SVG2 spec [specifically notes it as something that should be addressed](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#painting-MarkerUnitsAttribute), though that doesn't help you now.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I guess I'll have to position and size them myself.